# $X$ ~ $xe^{-x}$ for $I (x > 0)$. $Y$, given $X = x$, is uniformly distributed over $(0,x)$. Find...

Tags: probability, expectation

**a)** $f_Y (y | X = x) =$ ?

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,E (y | X = x) =$ ?

**b)** $f(x,y) =$ ?

**c)** $f_Y (y) =$ ?

**d)** $f_X (x | Y = y) =$ ?

**e)** $E(X | Y = y) =$ ?

**My work:**

a)  $f_Y(y|x) = \frac{1}{(x-0)} = \frac{1}{x}\\E(y|x) = \int_0^x y f(y|x)dy = \int_0^x\frac{y}{x} = \frac{x}{2}$

b)  $f(x,y) = f(y|x)f(x) = \frac{1}{x}( xe^{-x}) = e^{-x}$

c)  $f_Y(y) = \int_0^\infty f(x,y)dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} dx = 1$

d) $f_X(x|y)= \frac{f(x,y)}{f(y)} = e^{-x}$

e) $E(x|y) = \int_0^\infty x f(x|y) dx = \int_0^\infty x e^{-x} dx$ Which is the mean with exponential distribution so, $E(x|y) = \frac{1}{\lambda} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$

Does my work seem to be correct?

Comment: You need to keep track of when your densities are zero. For example, $f_{Y|X}(y\mid x)$ is only $1/x$ for $y\in (0,x)$. Similarly, $f(x,y)$ is not $e^{-x}$ for all $(x,y)$.

Comment: @StefanHansen That is a good point, I will add that in. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) $f_Y(y|X=x)=\frac1x\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt x}$
, $E(Y|X=x)=\frac12x$

b) $f(x,y)=\mathrm e^{-x}\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt x}$

c) $f_Y(y)=\mathrm e^{-y}\mathbf 1_{y\gt0}$

d) $f_X(x|Y=y)=\mathrm e^{-(x-y)}\mathbf 1_{x\gt y}$

e) $E(X|Y=y)=y+1$